# Why does react-testing-library not wait for input into a react-hooks-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am trying to test a Form, built with `react-hook-form`. I test by putting text into the fields and clicking the submit Button.
Then i assert that the Button disappears and is replaced by a simple "Thank you!" message.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-react-hook-form-question-mmh9tz

The Problem is, that `react-testing-library` does not seem to wait until the transition happens and can't find the thank you message.

So far i have tried using: `act` `waitFor` and `waitForElementToBeRemoved` as well as using `await` on the `userEvent.click()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userEvent.type` returns a promise so it needs to `await`

After making this change, it works for me here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rtl-react-hook-form-question-forked-3op0r5?file=%2Fsrc%2FForm.test.tsx%3A22%2C1

However, if I make the same change in the codesandbox link you have shared, it does not work, probably some environment issue.

Comment: It took some while to find but it was due to @testing-library/react@13.4.0 and testing-library/user-event@14.4.3 installing different versions of @testing-library/dom. An update to the latest versions fixed that!